# Creating objects from json does not work as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

There is something wrong when I try to fill the contacts list with contacts from json. When I iterate in map over `contactsJson` and add the created contact in list then the resulting list is empty.

```
var response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('...'));
var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
var contactsJson = jsonResponse as List;
print(contactsJson); // output is below
List<Contact> contacts = [];
contactsJson.map((contact) => contacts.add(Contact.fromJson(contact)));
if (contacts.isEmpty) print('the list is empty'); // output: the list is empty
```

this is the content of `contactsJson`, it looks like a list

```
> [{id: 1, name: Leanne Graham, username: Bret, email:
> Sincere@april.biz, address: {street: Kulas Light, suite: Apt. 556,
> city: Gwenborough, zipcode: 92998-3874, geo: {lat: -37.3159, lng:
> 81.1496}}, phone: 1-770-736-8031 x56442, website: hildegard.org, company: {name: Romaguera-Crona, catchPhrase: Multi-layered
> client-server neural-net, bs: harness real-time e-markets}}, {id: 2, name: Ervin Howell, ...
```

where the model

```
class Contact {
  const Contact({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.company,
  });

  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final Company company;

  factory Contact.fromJson(Map json) => Contact(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      username: json['username'],
      email: json['email'],
      company: Company.fromJson(json['company']));

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Contact{name: $name, email: $email, company: $company}';
  }
}
```

Where is the error?

Comment: ‘contactsJson.forEach((contact) => contacts.add(Contact.fromJson(contact)))’ use foreach,not map, map is lazy and you need to add .toList

Comment: @Nagual you were right, adding ` .toList` fixed it all, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned in the comment section, Yes it is lazy.

ways to fix.

1)

```
contactVar = contactsJson.map((contact) => Contact.fromJson(contact)).toList();
```

2. 

```
contactsJson.forEach((contact) { contacts.add(Contact.fromJson(contact)); });
```

3. for (var contact in contactsJson) { contacts.add(Contact.fromJson(contact)); }